# How to navigate to one module to another in Automotive, One is java module other is kotlin module

Tags: android-studio, auto, android-auto, android-automotive, automotive

here i need to navigate(intent) Java module to kotlin module complete different functionality with two services i used `

```
<service
        android:name=".common.PlacesCarAppService"
        android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
        <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.POI"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

<service
    android:name=".common.mapbox.MainCarAppService"
    android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
    <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.NAVIGATION" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>`
```

so am handling these two module from automotive module can please suggest me how launch these different module from onclick listener from the buttons

```
GridItem.IMAGE_TYPE_ICON)
                    .setTitle("Navigation")
                    .setOnClickListener(
                            () ->{

           PlaceCategoryListScreen newScreen = new PlaceCategoryListScreen(getCarContext()); // Replace 'Screen' with the actual screen class you want to push
                                    getScreenManager().push(newScreen);
                            }
                           
                               
                    )
                    .build();

  GridItem.IMAGE_TYPE_ICON)
                    .setTitle("mapbox")
                    .setOnClickListener(
                            () ->{

           PExampleApplication newScreen = new ExampleApplication(getCarContext()); 
                                getScreenManager().push(newScreen);

                            }
                           
                               
                    )
                    .build();
```

here am looking module navigation solution and multiple service used in android manifest please give detail information documentation, thanks in advance